# Getting null pointer exception on more than one request parameter in curl GET request

Tags: rest, http, curl

1, Curl command for single request parameter:

`curl --insecure -X GET "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost/test?pageSize=1`
Working fine.

2, Curl command for mulitple request parameters:

`curl --insecure -X GET "Content-Type:application/json"  https://localhost/test?pageSize=1&pageNumber=0`
I'm getting pageNumber is null, throwing null pointer exception

Sample Java controller class

```
@Controller
    @RequestMapping("/api/test")
    public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, producesMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getTest(
                @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
                @RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", required = false) Integer pageNumbe,
                HttpServletRequest hsrequest, HttpServletResponse hsresponse) {
    //implementation
    }
```

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: 1) You don't need a content-type header field on GET, as you are not sending content. 2) You likely need to quote the URL, otherwise "&" will be interpreted by the shell as operator.

Comment: Adding quote to URL solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2, Curl command for mulitple request parameters:

curl --insecure -X GET "Content-Type:application/json"  https://localhost/test?pageSize=1&pageNumber=0

Solution: Added quotes to URL

curl --insecure -X GET "Content-Type:application/json"  "https://localhost/test?pageSize=1&pageNumber=0"